# Was following a tutorial on android development. Did everything same yet im getting errors

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






    }
    public void onBtnTxt(View view){
        TextView txtApp = findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
        EditText inpTxt = findViewById(R.id.input);
        txtApp.setText(inpTxt.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

this is java code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome!!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.339" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick= "onBtnTxt"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.286" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Your name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtMsg" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is xml code

```
2023-01-25 22:07:15.960 9062-9062/com.example.firstapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2023-01-25 22:07:15.962 9062-9062/com.example.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 9062
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:446)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:13216)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:7821)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2716)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:12450)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1896)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:428)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1820)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3360)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:122)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:140)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:599)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3089)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:342)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4779)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2571)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2081)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2072)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2548)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2023-01-25 22:07:15.963 9062-9062/com.example.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441)
            ... 52 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onBtnTxt(MainActivity.java:25)
            ... 54 more
```

this is the error log

I was following android development for beginner course by freecodecamp from youtube.
My android studio is properly installed. I have installed "pie" with api level of 28 as the virtual device. After doing everything exactly same i get this error. My app suddenly crashes and shows fatal error.

Please help Im completely new in this.

Comment: `EditText inpTxt = findViewById(R.id.input);` that is not the correct id for your `EditText`.  It is `editTextTextPersonName`.  instead you provided the id of the layout hence the class cast exception: `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll scroll down in your stack starce you will see this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
    at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onBtnTxt(MainActivity.java:25)
```

In your `onBtnTxt(View view)` method you wrote

```
EditText inpTxt = findViewById(R.id.input);
```

but in the layout file you gave this id (id.input) to the root view which is a `constraintlayout`, not an `EditText`

change it to

```
EditText inpTxt = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
```